# Group Datagridview rows and add subheaders using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

Can anybody help me with my problem on how to group rows in datagridview and add subheader on top of the rows.

I've tried this code, and it was successful but it does not satisfy my need.

```
Private Sub dgvCurriculum_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As 
     DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles 
       dgvCurriculum.CellFormatting
    If e.RowIndex > 0 And e.ColumnIndex = 0 Then
        If dgvCurriculum.Item(0, e.RowIndex - 1).Value = e.Value Then
            e.Value = ""
        ElseIf e.RowIndex < dgvCurriculum.Rows.Count - 1 Then
            dgvCurriculum.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = 
    Color.White
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I want to do it like this, if you mind to check on the image i uploaded.

[Click me to view this image please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXui8.jpg)

Please, I badly needed a help.. Thanks

Comment: Well, what code have you tried that attempts to satisfy `your need` ?

Comment: I already provided you the code, but i want to do it more like the image i uploaded earlier.. Please kindly give me a hand on this, show me a way on how to do it, or maybe share some code can do.. i appreciate any help.. thanks..